# Python, SqlAlchemy: Many to many relationship, find those without

Tags: python, sql, database-design, sqlalchemy, pylons

Say I have two types of objects, `Movies` and `Tags`, related by the [ORM](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html#) in a [many to many relationship](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many) with an association table indicated by the `secondary` argument to `relationship()`, and I want to be able to find, say, all the `Movies` without `Tags`? What kind of query would I run to achieve that effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [any()](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/internals.html?highlight=any#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any), which is specifically useful for this kind of queries.

```
query = session.query(Movies).filter(~Movies.tags.any())
```

*Here `tags` is the many-to-many relationship name to `Tags`.*

Answer (score 2):

If the TagId was part of the Movies object, this would be a simple case of checking if the TagId on Movies was null:

```
session.query(Movies).filter(Movies.TagId == None).all()
```

But your many-to-many comment suggests a MoviesTags link entity, so its trickier and involves linking to MoviesTags using a left outer join.

There's [a good guide to writing and debugging](http://www.luckydonkey.com/2007/05/16/more-sqlalchemy-this-time-explicit-joins/) similar SQL queries.  And you basically want to end up with:

```
select Movies.name from Movies 
left outer join MoviesTags on Movies.MovieId = MoviesTags.MovieId 
where MoviesTags.TagId is null
```

Comment: Unless I'm reading it wrong, the [documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.__eq__) seems to indicate that the '== None' construct will product a NOT EXISTS clause for many-to-many as well?

Comment: Yeah, can't follow your first suggestion. I don't have a TagId in the Movies table because it is many to many. I will look about following your second suggestion.